# Citrusframework: Verify that http server has not received any more requests

Tags: citrus-framework

In my test case, I perform the `http().receive()` action for each expected request to the citrus http server.

Now I'd like to verify that there weren't any more requests after the expected ones. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `receiveTimeout()` test action that expects that no messages are received on a given endpoint:

```
receiveTimeout(httpServer)
    .timeout(5000);
```

This will make sure that no requests are received from 'httpServer' endpoint for 5000 ms. The action fails in case a message arrives at this endpoint in that time.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I missed that somehow in the docs. Thanks a lot!